# Get all structure fields from raw data and structure definition

Tags: c, structure, endianness

I am looking for a tool which can take a structure definition and raw data(byte aligned) as input and output the data in structured form (show the value of each field of the structure).

Comment: You need to supply some more information. Can you post some code, or show what you've already tried?

Comment: not sure by byte aligned you mean the whole data is byte aligned or each individual field is byte aligned.

Answer (score 0):

This is not so easy to answer since the raw data from the structure depends on the data alignment and padding.

What you could do is to write a small C program that copies the byte array into a structure object:

```
MyStruct struct;
char byteArray[] = { 0x10, 0x20, 0x30 };
memcpy(struct, byteArray, sizeof(struct));
```

Then you can watch the structure variable in a debugger.

It's important to use the same compiler options for data alignment and padding to compile this program as it was used for creating the raw byte array out of  the structure.